# How to get id of created record?

Tags: angular

I want to get the id (`hour_id`) of the created record.  What do I need to do for that? Add `hour_id` to the form? or something else?

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
  teams_id: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
  team_name: new FormControl({ value: "", disabled: true }, Validators.required),
  well: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
  layer: new FormControl(null),
  chock: new FormControl(null)
})

onSave() {
  this._service.create(this.form.value).subscribe(
    () => {
      this._toast.success("Saved.");
      // console.log(this.form.controls.hour_id) ?
    },
    error => {
      this._toast.error(error.error.message);
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to log the service answer and check if it is in there

```
onSave() {
  this._service.create(this.form.value).subscribe(
    response => {
      this._toast.success("Saved.");
      console.log(response);
    },
    error => {
      this._toast.error(error.error.message);
    }
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new form control with the same name that you would be returning from the server. Suppose you are returning the value `hour_id`, add hour_id to the form.

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
  hour_id: new FormControl(null),
  teams_id: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
  team_name: new FormControl({ value: "", disabled: true }, Validators.required),
  well: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
  layer: new FormControl(null),
  chock: new FormControl(null)
})

onSave() {
  this._service.create(this.form.value).subscribe(
    () => {
      this._toast.success("Saved.");
      console.log(this.form.controls.hour_id.value) ?
    },
    error => {
      this._toast.error(error.error.message);
    }
  )
}
```

When you patch the value to your form with the response returned, the `hour_id` would get updated.

Comment: If I do this, will he not try to make id empty?   `hour_id: new FormControl(null)`

Comment: @user12543392 It depends on your scenario. If the backend updates the value of `hour_id` if you send it, then try not sending that value to the backend when you are saving. Initially it will remain empty but on saving it will get updated and if you are showing it on front end, it will automatically be shown if you patch the value.